# Why is the same commit in different branches missing a tag?

Tags: git, tags

I have two branches.  `Branch_1` and `Branch_2`.  They both have the same commit (i.e. verified this through the `sha1 ID`).

Tags in `git` are not specific to branches.  They are pointers to commits.  I expect the commit -- which exists in both branches -- to have the same label(s) (i.e. `master`, `remotes/origin/master`, `my_tag`, etc).

When I run git tag on `branch_1`, I can see the tag `my_tag` for commit `abcde123...` .

When I run git tag on `branch_2`, however, I do not see the tag `my_tag` for commit `abcde123...` .  Rather, it's missing completely (i.e. even brought up `gitk` of both branches and the only label its missing is the tag).

What is happening and/or what did I do wrong to get in this state?

Comment: What is the SHA of each object, and what does the tag file contain?

Comment: `git tag`, by itself, just lists *all* tags. Even with additional options, when listing tags, the *current* branch is irrelevant unless you've done something like `git tag --contains HEAD` so as to resolve the name `HEAD` to a hash ID. Actual commands-and-outputs might help us diagnose what's going on.

Comment: There is something being misunderstood here, because the way git stores objects it simply isn't sensible to say "when I'm on this branch there is a tag pointing to this commit, but when I'm on this branch it's gone".  If I take all you've said at face value, the most likely thing seems that you have two clones, each checked out for a different branch, and one of the clones has the tag while the other does not.  If you're using two clones to keep work trees for two branches, consider using `git worktree` instead to avoid such issues.  But this is all just a guess, and ultimately I ...

Comment: ... agree with torek's comment, that seeing actual commands (and their output) would give us more to go on.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Embarrassingly, that was the situation.  Yes, using `git worktree` would help avoid such issues in the future.